# Cannot understand the difference between gluster and gluster-block volumes

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, storage, kubernetes-pod, openshift-enterprise

I am having hard time getting the difference between GlusterFS and gluster-block volumes

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/install_config/persistent_storage/persistent_storage_glusterfs.html

As you see in openshift documentation it is mentioned that Glusterfs can only be mounted by one node/client at a time. what does  that mean? Does it mean that if I use kubernetes with 3 container I cannot share it with the 3 containers? Or does it mean that if I have a deployment in kubernetes and 3 pods only these 3 pods can use the volume and other deployment wont be able to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing on documentation from [openshift](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/install_config/persistent_storage/persistent_storage_glusterfs.html#overview-block-volumes) and [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/#glusterfs)

> **Gluster-block volumes** can only be mounted by one node/client at a time which is in contrast to **GlusterFS** volumes which can be mounted by multiple nodes/clients
>
> A **glusterfs volume** allows a **Glusterfs** (an open source networked filesystem) volume to be mounted into your Pod. Unlike emptyDir, which is erased when a Pod is removed, the contents of a glusterfs volume are preserved and the volume is merely unmounted. This means that a **glusterfs volume** can be pre-populated with data, and that data can be “handed off” between Pods. **GlusterFS** can be mounted by multiple writers simultaneously.

There is an [example](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/volumes/glusterfs) which provide information about how to allow containers use GlusterFS volumes

---

> A [**Pod**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/glossary/?all=true#term-pod) is the basic execution unit of a Kubernetes application -> the smallest and simplest unit in the Kubernetes object model that you create or deploy. A Pod represents processes running on your [Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/glossary/?all=true#term-cluster).
>
> You can have one or more containers inside Pod. All containers share a **unique IP, storage, network and any other specification applied to the pod**.
>
> A Pod can specify a set of shared [storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-overview/#storage) Volumes. A**ll containers in the Pod can access the shared volumes, allowing those containers to share data**. Volumes also allow persistent data in a Pod to survive in case one of the containers within needs to be restarted. See [Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) for more information on how Kubernetes implements shared storage in a Pod.